# Facebook Login Method Onload

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I'd have just a question. Is possible make a onLoad method on facebook login api?

Here is my code:

```
loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by `onLoad()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

CallbackManager  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback() {

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

});
```

and use this

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }